# DRF token authentication

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-csrf, django-permissions

For a drf project i am use both session and token authentication.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

So is it possible to make api calls without the csrf token here, because i tried with only the heater "Authorization: Token " and it returns "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."

The thing is i want the session authentication for using the browsable api in drf and token auth for programatic calls
..
I hope that is clear..

Comment: Two questions: what is your `DEBUG` setting? Are you using SSL? DRF/Django will enforce the need for CSRF when `DEBUG = False` and the protocol is insecure. However, if you're on an encrypted connection (or a dev instance denoted by `DEBUG`), a token should be sufficient.

Comment: Debug is True. I am not using ssl.

Comment: use ```@csrf_exempt``` decorator to ignore the csrf error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom authentication.
Use cookie authentication for browsable API and token authentication for programmatic requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can You give an example?